# Do you have a clever hack to work around svn:externals not being supported in bzr-svn

Tags: svn, version-control, bazaar, svn-externals, bzr-svn

I'm using bzr to access a Subversion repository.  Which is great, but the repository uses quite a few svn:externals properties to bring in code from related projects.

[Bzr-svn doesn't support svn:externals](http://bazaar-vcs.org/BzrForeignBranches/Subversion#limitations) yet.

Is there a good way to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today another option is available: [bzr-externals plugin](https://launchpad.net/bzr-externals). Check it!

Comment: bzr-externals won't look at the actual svn:externals file properties though, will it?

Comment: @jelmer No I don't think it does, and quickly scanning it's launchpad page it doesn't mention svn other than saying it's like svn-extenals.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on emulating svn:externals in bzr. It's not related to bzr-svn but instead tries to provide generic solution. Project still in the alpha stage but many things are working today. You can have a look at the project and it's docs.
https://launchpad.net/bzr-scmproj

This plugin does not support svn:externals natively, but you can bring the required values to project config. If your svn:externals is not changed often it will work for you well.

Comment: Cool.  I'll have to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, externals will probably be supported in a couple of months, when nested tree support in Bazaar itself lands.